# translateX value does not get updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to build a photo slider. For now I don't mind if the way I am doing it isn't that good. What I am interested to know is why after I'm changing the `TranslateX` value via jQuery and then printing it to the console it doesn't print the changed value of it?

```js
var translateX;

function transX_func() {
    var matrix = $('#img1, #img2, #img3, #img4, #img5').css('transform').split(/[()]/);
    var newArray = new Array();
    newArray = matrix[1].split(',');

    for (a in newArray) {
        newArray[a] = parseInt(newArray[a], 10); 
    }

    var transX = newArray[4];
    translateX = transX;
}

$('#next').click(function(event){       
    event.preventDefault();
    transX_func();
    if (translateX == 0) {
        $('#img1, #img2, #img3, #img4, #img5').css({
            'transform': 'translateX(-100%)'
        });
        transX_func();
        console.log(translateX);
    }   
    else {}
});
```

EDIT:
due to your comments i have added the entire code in here : http://codepen.io/SaharShukrun/pen/pyzeRB

this is'nt the code i originally had the problem with but it is very similar , stills makes the same problem.

i have solved this problem by understanding what makes the value of the var to not get updated and i have posted the answer below.

Comment: maybe console.log is not waiting for transX_func() to complete. Have you checked that?

Comment: A simple MCVE would help to find the issue...

Comment: How can this question get so much upvotes while instead it should be closed because missing relavnt MCVE??? Can someone reproduces it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of the behaviour since we don't have the full context of your snippet (css transform => initial values, when/how it changes...), but with a starting point like `transform: translateX(0);` to be sure that 
your matrix doesn't return `matrix =  ["none"]`...

Your function seems to display the value correctly. [see codepen](http://codepen.io/Ankrat/pen/WrVBMx)

Note, I realised this answer wasn't an *answer*

You changed the value of css transform to `-100%` which return the calculated value (ie: img width is 800px, will return -800).

This value doesn't change, hence display the same number. I might be wrong again, but adding an incremental counter (added in the codepen above) change the value and display the newly calculated one.

I hope this, at least, give you some leads...

Answer (score 0):

first of all i'd like to thank Yann for the very much detailed answer, and that you took the time to write all of it.

at a second look i noticed i didn't put the full MCVE which probably could solve my next problem.
i am a new user here so ill try and pick up quickly :).

i will add now the entire MCVE so you could look at the could and reproduce it.

and finally i came to realise why the value wasn't updated.
infact, it did. in a 2sec delay because i used "transition 2s".so the function added the value that was at that time and not the full value after the change because the value changes gradually.

when i deleted the "transition:2s" everything was fine.
tho it is not a good solution because i do need to make to animation.
right now i am thinking about how i can do that.

thanks everyone for the replies .
this is the working code with out the animation (which i am working on understanding how to do so )

```
var translateX = 0;

var firstVal = 0;

function transX_func(){

    var matrix = $('#img1,#img2,#img3,#img4,#img5').css('transform').split(/[()]/);
    console.log("matrix = ", matrix);
    var newArray = new Array();         
    newArray = matrix[1].split(',');

    for (a in newArray ) {
        newArray[a] = parseInt(newArray[a], 10); 
    }
    var transX = newArray[4];
    translateX = transX;
    console.log("translateX inner = ",translateX);
}


$('#next').click(function(event){       
    event.preventDefault();
    if(translateX == 0){
        $('#img1,#img2,#img3,#img4,#img5').css({'transform':'translateX(-100%)'});      
        transX_func();
        firstVal = translateX;
    }
    else{
        var newVal = firstVal + translateX;
        $('#img1,#img2,#img3,#img4,#img5').css({'transform':'translateX(' + newVal + 'px)'});       
        transX_func();
    }


}); 

$('#prev').click(function(){

});
```